# Struggling to get a chart with modified JSON format

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm very new to d3js. I did a bar chart using one json file. It works very fine. But now I changed the JSON file format due to some unavoidable reasons.
My previous json was:

```
[ 
    {"name":"bike","value":98},
    {"name":"car","value":52},
    {"name":"bus","value":20},
    {"name":"van","value":65} 
]
```

Code is :

```
d3.json("sample.json", function(error, data) {
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    var chart = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    chart.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    var bar = chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g");

    bar.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
});
```

This is my new json file:

```
[ 
    {"category":"bike","bike":38,"car":0,"bus":0,"van":0},
    {"category":"car","bike":0,"car": 50,"bus":0,"van":0,},
    {"category":"bus","bike":0,"car": 0,"bus":14,"van":0},
    {"category":"van","bike":0,"car": 0,"bus":0,"van":43} 
]
```

I want to get a chart like same as previous one. Data with "0" (zero) shouldn't appear in chart.
Pls help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just a note: I would seriously consider adjusting your "new" json format, as you carry a lot of redundant information (or rather non-information) in it

Comment: yes, its true. I'm working with very large data. I have written one common script to get json file. This format supports my other d3 codes(ex: grouped bar chart) except this one. writing separate script is additional work and that is not fair.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide an explanation of your new format, and I'm not sure how your previous format was working (given the `x` attribute setting) but adjusting to the new format should be as simple as

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.category); })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[d.category]); })
```

And similar changes elsewhere. (e.g. for the height)

Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Its not working yaar. I want to know how to fetch particular required data from json to our d3 code. For ex: ** [ {"name":"abc","score":43,"age":38,"match":20},
{"name":"rts","score":47,"age":34,"match":15}, {"name":"xyz","score":56,"age":41,"match":17} ] ** Here I want only **name** and **score** to be taken. How to do that??